# SQL Server : table without primary ID , NO Unique Column and Time Stamp

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

In our server we have a table of almost 2 GB, but problem is this table has no unique / primary key and no TimeStamp either. I am going to migration but without a unique value or / primary key or timestamp script is not working .

SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Comment: *If it doesn't have a primary key, it's really not a table* ....

Comment: Then the first thing you want to do is to remove duplicated rows. the second thing is to create at least one unique index on that table, that will be your primary key.

Comment: So what are you asking? I am not seeing any question. Why not place a primary key on the table?

Comment: I cannot add any column now , because of my source code . any place insert query will not be work . Is there any way that i can generate timestamp or serial number during select query for temporary

Comment: You don't need to add a column, you just need to enforce row uniqueness. a primary key can be composite from multiple columns, it doesn't have to be a single column. In fact, it can even be composed of all the columns in the table if it has to.